# CSS: transform-origin

Tags: css, css-transitions, scale, css-transforms

I have a problem with transformation in CSS.

```
#test{
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#test:hover{
  transform : scale(2);
  transition:1s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin : left top;
}
```

The problem is when you hover mouse over the `div` it is floating slightly up, and what I want to do is stick to the one place, and grow/rescale only right and bottom side.

[Here is codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyYPMM).

I hope You guys understood what I want to say.

Comment: check which transform origin you require -- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

Comment: The thing is, when I erase transition there is no problem..

Comment: ease-in-out - specifies a transition effect with a slow start and end -- is that what you want? -- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set which property the transition should animate, and in your case it is `transform` that should be added to `transition: 1s ease-in-out;`, like this `transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;`.

```css
#test{
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#test:hover{
  transform : scale(2);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin : left top;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  TEST
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
    width:100px;height:100px;
    border:1px solid red; 



    transition-property: transform;
transition-duration: 200ms;
transition-timing-function: ease-in;
transition-delay: 50ms;
transform: scale(0, 0);
transform-origin: center left;


}
button:hover + div{
    transform: scale(1, 1)
}

<button>hello</button>

<div>status</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

transform-origin property compliments the transform property. It allows us to tell the browser exactly at what coordinates we want the transformation to happen, using just CSS. Here’s how:

transform-origin:[x][y]

replace x and y with percentage values like 50% for mid, 0% for start and 100% for ending positions respectively. I’ve made a pen for helping you to understand this once and for all.

I wrote a complete article here: 
https://medium.com/@RajaRaghav/understanding-css-transform-origin-property-2ef5f8c50777
with illustrative examples